# Copy Files to SMB Mount (says it's full but it really isn't)

Tags: smb

I'm trying to drag and drop a file from my Mac to an SMB server but it's saying there isn't enough space.  When I do a `df` it's showing only 20 MB when I know it's a 3TB server.

```
sora:~ steve$ df -h
Filesystem           Size   Used  Avail Capacity  iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2        112Gi   87Gi   25Gi    78% 22767615    6644753   77%   /
devfs               183Ki  183Ki    0Bi   100%      634          0  100%   /dev
map -hosts            0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%        0          0  100%   /net
map auto_home         0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%        0          0  100%   /home
//admin@riku/media   20Mi   20Mi    0Bi   100%        0 18446744073709551615    0%   /Volumes/media
```

Why is it showing up this way? Is there a way I can ignore it and copy the file over anyway?

Comment: Same problem here. I'm using a NAS under Snake OS and samba3 package. Can not write or paste files and it returns "there is not enough space at destination drive" or something like that

Comment: What OS build version is your Mac? The smb2 code on Mavericks should handle much larger SMB share sizes than 3 TB.